# Is probabilistic modeling the same thing as Bayesian modeling?

Tags: bayesian, probabilistic-programming

When titles, books, and posts refer to probabilistic modeling, coupled with it I usually see the word "Bayesian" near by and all around. If we were to think of this as a ven diagram, are they the same circle? Is Bayesian modeling within probabilistic modeling? What's the compliment of the intersection of Bayesian and probabilistic modeling ?

Comment: "Is Bayesian modeling within probabilistic modeling?" - yes.
Frequentist methods for instance are probabilistic methods which are not Bayesian. Bayesian approaches look at posterior probabilities and therefore assume a prior distribution.
One very common probabilistic approach which is not Bayesian is the Maximum Likelihood Estimation (even if it can be seen sometimes as a very special case of it...)
This would be a good reading (look at the answers ;) ): http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180420/why-is-maximum-likelihood-estimation-considered-to-be-a-frequentist-technique

Comment: I think the connotation of the term "probabilistic model" depends a lot on context, both in terms of the intellectual field in which its being used and the historical period in which its being used. For example, in recent decades in Cognitive Science, "probabilistic model" usually alludes to a Bayesian model. But I don't think that the term inherently refers to a Bayesian model.